# How to solve this issue in Android Studio Emulator OpenGLRenderer Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without

Tags: java, android-studio, openglrenderer

2024-03-07 16:25:32.772  5575-5575  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.background1              V  Currently set values for:

2024-03-07 16:25:32.773  5575-5575  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.background1              V    angle_gl_driver_selection_pkgs=[]

2024-03-07 16:25:32.773  5575-5575  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.background1              V    angle_gl_driver_selection_values=[]

2024-03-07 16:25:32.775  5575-5575  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.background1              V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.background1: false

2024-03-07 16:25:32.775  5575-5575  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.background1              V  com.example.background1 is not listed in per-application setting

2024-03-07 16:25:32.776  5575-5575  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.background1              V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.

2024-03-07 16:25:32.835  5575-5605  libEGL                  com.example.background1              D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so

2024-03-07 16:25:32.845  5575-5605  libEGL                  com.example.background1              D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so

2024-03-07 16:25:32.858  5575-5605  libEGL                  com.example.background1              D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

2024-03-07 16:25:33.134  5575-5575  AppCompatDelegate       com.example.background1              D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found

2024-03-07 16:25:33.444  5575-5575  ple.background1         com.example.background1              W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)

2024-03-07 16:25:33.445  5575-5575  ple.background1         com.example.background1              W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)

2024-03-07 16:25:33.536  5575-5575  Compatibil...geReporter com.example.background1              D  Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10192; state: ENABLED

2024-03-07 16:25:33.919  5575-5575  Compatibil...geReporter com.example.background1              D  Compat change id reported: 237531167; UID 10192; state: DISABLED

2024-03-07 16:25:33.922  5575-5575  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.background1              W  Unknown dataspace 0

2024-03-07 16:25:34.067  5575-5603  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.background1              W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...

2024-03-07 16:25:34.067  5575-5603  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.background1              W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS

2024-03-07 16:25:34.068  5575-5575  AutofillManager         com.example.background1              D  notifyViewEnteredForFillDialog:1073741824

2024-03-07 16:25:34.069  5575-5575  AutofillManager         com.example.background1              D  notifyViewEnteredForFillDialog:1073741825

2024-03-07 16:25:34.069  5575-5575  AutofillManager         com.example.background1              D  notifyViewEnteredForFillDialog:1073741826

2024-03-07 16:25:34.072  5575-5575  AutofillManager         com.example.background1              D  notifyViewEnteredForFillDialog:1073741827

2024-03-07 16:25:34.112  5575-5603  Gralloc4                com.example.background1              I  mapper 4.x is not supported

2024-03-07 16:25:34.132  5575-5603  OpenGLRenderer          com.example.background1              E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.

2024-03-07 16:25:34.368  5575-5575  Compatibil...geReporter com.example.background1              D  Compat change id reported: 78294732; UID 10192; state: ENABLED

2024-03-07 16:25:35.835  5575-5575  WindowOnBackDispatcher  com.example.background1              W  sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@1121899